# Bitwise operations, assembly

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, avr, atmega

I've got a task to change the bit location from

> START bit7 | bit6 | bit5 | bit4 | bit3 | bit2 | bit1 | bit0
>
> FINAL bit3' | bit2' | bit7 | bit6 | bit1 | bit0 | bit5' | bit4'

Using the bitwise and shift/rolling instructions.

I don't know how to move them different way than shifting and rolling. Should I use only one or multiple registers to do that?

Comment: What processor is that for? How to do this depends strongly on what instructions are available. Filling this in at http://programming.sirrida.de/calcperm.php suggests moving the bits in four groups of two, which makes sense, I would have done that myself too.

Comment: ldi r16, $F0 ;gives value F0 to r16. And then I was using commands like 'lsl', 'lsr', etc.

Comment: The approach is faitly straightforward. Take a 2 bit chunk, shift it to the right place. Zero out all other bits by AND. Then OR the chunk with previously processed chunks. Do so 4 times. Yes, you'll need several registers - one to work with the current chunk, another to accumulate the result, yet another for the source. I have no idea about your system's assembly, but that's the general approach.

Comment: How to take 2bit chunk? Do I need 4 registers?

Comment: You take a 2 bit chunk by looking at the scheme above and thinking "here's a two bit chunk I'm gonna work with" :) On the code level, it's just shifting and masking. For chunk with bits 0 and 1, you shift left by two, then AND by 1100b. And so forth.

Comment: Not on Atmel, folks. Conceptually yes, but that would produce exceptionally slow code. It's an 8 bit microcontroller with 1 bit shifts/rolls only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using shift and rol, you should be able to do it with two registers, wasting the original in the progress.

Shifting A right through carry *copies* the left most bit into carry.
Shifting B right through carry *copies* that bit to register B and shifts the LSB to carry.

By sequence of

```
1 - ROR A,A,1     // A = _7654321, --> carry = '0'
2 - ROR B,B,1     // B = 0_______, --> carry = 'x' / don't care
3 - ROR A,A,1     // A = x_765432, --> carry = '1'
4 - ROR B,B,1     // B = 10______, --> carry = 'x' / don't care
// this has copied two bits from A to B while shifting both

5 - ROR B,B,1     // B = x10_____,
6 - ROR B,B,1     // B = xx10____,

repeat steps 1-4 again for B to contain bits '3 2 _ _ 1 0 _ _'
```

(And this is half of the solution)